# Why isn't SKSpriteNode responding to applyForce or applyImpulse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a sprite node that's appearing and falling in response to the gravity applied on its attached `physicsBody`.

Great.

Now, I'd like to use `applyForce` to push it a little bit in some direction while it's falling.

Unfortunately, no matter how small I make the `physicsBody.mass` or `physicsWorld.gravity` or how large I make the `applyForce` vector -- the `applyForce` vector appears to be ignored.

**When I comment out the** `self.physicsWorld.gravity` **line, I see** `applyForce` **working as expected**

#### How do I achieve "pushing" the physics body using applyForce whilst gravity is applied?

---

Here's my .h

```
// GameScene.h


#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface GameScene : SKScene

@end
```

And the .m

```
// GameScene.m

#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene ()
@property NSMutableArray *bubblesToPop;

@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.size = view.bounds.size;
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 1.0);

    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bubble"];

    sprite.yScale = 0.5;
    sprite.xScale = 0.5;
    sprite.name = @"bubble";
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.frame.size.height / 2.0);

    SKPhysicsBody *physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.frame.size.width];
    physicsBody.mass = 0.02;
    [physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(900, 900)];
    sprite.physicsBody = physicsBody;

    [self addChild:sprite];

}

@end
```

Comment: You need to assign the physicsBody to the sprite and then add the sprite to the scene prior to applying forces/impulses.

Comment: Moving the `applyForce` line below `addChild` totally worked. You should answer my question with that, because I looked on SO and the documentation for hours and it wasn't clear.

Comment: Also, I'd like to know why that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The body needs to be in the scene before Sprite Kit can determine how a force will affect it. The `applyForce` call on the physics body needs to happen after you `addChild` to the scene.

From Apple's documentation:

> **The physics simulation in Sprite Kit is performed by adding physics bodies to scenes. A physics body is a simulated physical object
>   connected to a node in the scene’s node tree.** It uses the node’s
>   position and orientation to place itself in the simulation...Each time
>   a scene computes a new frame of animation, **it simulates the effects
>   of forces and collisions on physics bodies connected to the node
>   tree.** It computes a final position, orientation, and velocity for
>   each physics body. Then, the scene updates the position and rotation
>   of each corresponding node [emphasis added].

Also, external factors contribute to how a physics body is affected by a force. For example, gravity, collisions, and force fields (iOS 8) must be taken into account when calculating the net force that is applied to a physics body. Therefore, the body needs to be in the scene before Sprite Kit can determine how a force will affect it.

Comment: That last sentence is the most important statement. Suggest moving it to the top and bolding.

Comment: Great answer! Still helping months later